# nginx proxy_pass to wrong domain

Tags: nginx

I want to proxy a example1.com to example2.com with nginx, configure as fllow

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example1.com;
    location / {
    expires off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_use_stale off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://www.example2.com/;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example1.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example1.com_error.log;
}
```

later I change to use example3.com:

```
server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example1.com;
        location / {
        expires off;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_cache_use_stale off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://www.example3.com/;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/www.example1.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example1.com_error.log;
    }
```

Whatever I restart nginx, it will proxy www.example1.com to www.example2.com, not www.example3.com.
Who has ever meet this question?

Nginx version:1.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Nginx syntax is correct, so your problem is elsewhere. Some things to check:

1. Do the domains resolve where you expect?

   - dig +short www.example2.com
   - dig +short www.example3.com
2. Are "www.example2.com" and "www.example3.com" on the same server? The problem could be with /that/ server configuration?
3. Make sure it's not some sort of browser caching issue. Use `curl` or another command-line HTTP testing tool that doesn't have a cache.

Comment: As you've said, the problem is elsewhere.I have found it and it had been solved, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your **nginx server**?
try
`sudo pkill nginx` and then `sudo nginx`

Comment: I have try `sudo pkill nginx` then `sudo nginx`, but it doesn't work